# How to store date and time in a file in a platform independent way

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to store a representation of a moment in time (date and time) in a binary file with Python.

My choice, for now, is to write an 8-byte representation in Unix time (seconds from 1970-1-1, 0h00). For this, I'm using `time`, specifically `gmtime`, `localtime` and `mktime`.

How much is this universal? From [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html), I got:

> The epoch is the point where the time starts, and is platform dependent. For Unix, the epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC). To find out what the epoch is on a given platform, look at time.gmtime(0).

When it says "to find out what the epoch is on a given platform" does it mean that different values may be produced by `mktime` depending on I'm using Debian, Windows, Mac or some other system?

Example:

```
>>> from time import localtime
>>> localtime(1649352786)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=14, tm_min=33, tm_sec=6, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=97, tm_isdst=0)
```

In other words, can `localtime(1649352786)` produce another date/time when run in different platforms?

If the answer is yes, how can I store "universal" and compact representation of a date/time? Using `pickle.dumps` in a `time.struct_time` object gives 53 bytes, which is way too much.

**EDIT**

From `time.time()` in [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time):

> **time.time() -> float**
> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. The specific date of the epoch and the handling of leap seconds is platform dependent. On Windows and most Unix systems, the epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC) and leap seconds are not counted towards the time in seconds since the epoch. This is commonly referred to as Unix time. To find out what the epoch is on a given platform, look at gmtime(0).

Comment: since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is just a point in time, why should it be platform-dependent? I think the docs are kind of misleading here, of course you *can* use another point in time as "epoch" but then it would not be the Unix epoch and the resulting time (if you calculate seconds from that epoch) not Unix time.

Comment: @ "*time.time(), which IS machine dependent*" - no, that *should* always refer to the Unix epoch, not something like "local time 1970-01-01". Different platforms might have different epochs, but time.time() refers to the Unix epoch, which is platform-independent.

Comment: @FObersteiner The docs say it is machine-dependent. See my edit. Or I'm misreading something?

Comment: I would have added an answer if I was absolutely sure ;-) To me, how the docs use the term "epoch" is not precise. Epoch doesn't necessarily mean Unix epoch, so I'm unsure what they're getting at. Leap seconds is another story; Unix time doesn't include them but that doesn't mean a certain platform doesn't need to handle them. Anyways, there's folks around here who will be able to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs indicate, it could be platform dependent. What you could do is instead of reading it in with local time, you could use datetimes 'fromtimestamp' method that returns the local date from the corresponding POSIX timestamp [(See docs)](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html?highlight=timestamp#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp).

example:

```
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(1649352786, tz=dt.timezone.utc)
```

This will give you the datetime, from a UTC timestamp, in the UTC timezone. If you leave off the tz argument, you will get the platform local time for the timestamp (i.e it will add/subtract the offset for the local timezone). This may or may not be desirable, depending on your use case.

---

Edit based off additional comments from OP.

Since the concern is that time.time() may give you an non-standard timestamp, in the cases that the platform isn't using the Unix Epoch (i'm not aware of any common/ non-embedded platforms not using it), Then you should do as the documetnation says and use `time.gmtime(0)` to get what the epoch is, and then i would suggest converting it into a valid UNIX timestamp, by calculating the offset from the platform epoch and the UNIX epoch, and then storing all timestamps as UNIX timestamps, so that any other platform reading the stored date will understand.

Comment: if you don't set the tz argument in `fromtimestamp`, that will again give you naive datetime representing local time. Use e.g. `dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(1649352786, tz=dt.timezone.utc)`

Comment: unixtimestamps are seconds from the epoch UTC, since the OP was using localtime, I assumed OP didn't mind using the time local to the machine. The key point is that using a UNIX timestamp, you can get localtime in a way that is platform independent. They way to achieve this is to use a function that takes in the timestamp assuming it is a UNIX timestamp, as `fromtimestamp` does. If Timezone is important, the OP can provide it.

Comment: OP was mixing in local time, yes, but Unix epoch is still Unix epoch and that refers to UTC. It has nothing to do with your machine's local time UTC offset. Unix time does not (or at least should not) include that. It is seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC, not local time.

Comment: if you feed Unix time to Python datetime's fromtimestamp method and ***don't set*** a tz, Python will add/subtract the UTC offset it can determine for the machine it runs on. That can be very convenient or very confusing. Because of the latter, I'd try to set a tz, and that's why I suggested it.

Comment: My question persists unfortunately, as `fromtimestamp` gives the time from the timestamp. But the timestamp is the one generated by `time.time()`, which IS machine dependent. So far, 1649352786 can represent distinct times depending on which machine it was generated. (Maybe I can make my question clearer...) :)

Comment: @FObersteiner, i see. Yes i can make an addition. to the answer to point that out.